# Can I apply graceful shutdown when using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka 3.0.3.RELEASE?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I developed the kafka consumer application based on Spring Cloud Stream 3.0.3.RELEASE.
(SpringBoot 2.3.4.RELEASE)

When I stop this application,
I want the consumer to gracefully shut down. [Similar Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883620/how-to-perform-a-graceful-application-shutdown-when-using-spring-cloud-stream-wi)

1. Stop polling new messages
2. Finish their work and Commit the offset to Kafka
3. Gracefully shut down application

Does the spring cloud stream default this work?
Then is there a related document?

---

For your information, I am using spring cloud stream kafka as below.

```
#Message handler
@Component
public class MessageHandler {

    @Bean
    public Consumer<MyEvent> handleMessage() {
        return message -> {...}
    }
...
}


#application.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        handleMessage-in-0:
          destination: myevent
          group: test-group
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 2
            concurrency: 10
      function:
        definition: handleMessage
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer you referenced, you can increase the `shutdownTimeout` container property (default 10 seconds) with a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean.

```java
@Bean
public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer() {
    return (container, dest, group) -> container.getContainerProperties()
            .setShutdownTimeout(30_000L);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was wondering if Spring Cloud Stream Kafka provides gracefully shut down.
As you said, if shutdownTimeout is the default setting of 10 seconds, graceful shutdown is already provided. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes; as long as you can process the records returned by the `poll()` within the `shutdownTimeout`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If the `max.poll.records` is changed to 1, the default `shutdownTimeout` setting of 10 seconds will be sufficient.