# Kafka Streams programmatically configuration not working

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm doing a spring boot application and I'm trying to configure kafka programmatically, but for some reason is still getting the properties from application.yaml instead of the ones I set programmatically

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(30000);

        return factory;
    }

    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "aaa"); // should crash since is not valid
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "app1");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
}

@Component
public class StreamListener {
    @StreamListener(TestStreams.TEST_STREAM_IN)
    public void testStream(@Payload GenericCustomEvent response, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Received generic event {} with headers {}", response, headers);
    }
}

public interface TestStreams {
    String TEST_STREAM_IN = "test-stream-in";

    @Input(TEST_STREAM_IN)
    SubscribableChannel inputTestStream();
}

@EnableBinding({TestStreams.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binder doesn't use a `KafkaListenerContainerFactory`, it creates the container itself from the yaml.

You can modify the container(s) by adding a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean.

Example here [Can I apply graceful shutdown when using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka 3.0.3.RELEASE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614658/can-i-apply-graceful-shutdown-when-using-spring-cloud-stream-kafka-3-0-3-release/67674509#67674509)